# Swift firebase [FIRDataSnapshot] error when i save

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

1. I'm receiving this error in my Firebase Database. I use `childByAutoId` to add them.
2. Categories below:

---

```
8fSAck6bK9Oq63FmvsnMu1eXqZH3
        -KTyha6hGYmx2x3yl6Za: "BUSINESS"
        -KTyha6ilqqqsR0TQgbR: "FAMILLE"
        -KTyha6ilqqqsR0TQgbS: "AMIS"
        -KTyha6ilqqqsR0TQgbT: "ECOLE"
        -KTyha6ilqqqsR0TQgbU: "UNIVERSITÉ"
        -KTyha6ilqqqsR0TQgbV: "SPORT"
        -KTyha6ilqqqsR0TQgbW: "ACTIVITÉ"
        -KTyha6ilqqqsR0TQgbX: "SOCIAL"
```

3. To populate my tableview, I use this:

   var listeCatégories: [FIRDataSnapshot]! = []
4. The result is:

---

```
[Snap (-KTyha6hGYmx2x3yl6Za) BUSINESS, 
Snap (-KTyha6ilqqqsR0TQgbR) FAMILLE,
Snap (-KTyha6ilqqqsR0TQgbS) AMIS,
Snap (-KTyha6ilqqqsR0TQgbT) ECOLE,
Snap (-KTyha6ilqqqsR0TQgbU) UNIVERSITÉ,
Snap (-KTyha6ilqqqsR0TQgbV) SPORT,
Snap (-KTyha6ilqqqsR0TQgbW) ACTIVITÉ,
Snap (-KTyha6ilqqqsR0TQgbX) SOCIAL]
```

5. I use `UIGestureRecognizer` to change order.
6. I want to save the new order in Firebase when the gesture is finished.

So I do this (-> the error)

```
self.ref.child("categories").child(self.user.uid).setValue(self.listeCatégories)
```

With `setValue`, I want to delete all row and save the new one with the new order. But I have this error :

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type
>   NSException

Can someone tell me where I'm wrong? Thanks a lot!

Comment: That's all the error says? Usually there's a bit more detail.

Comment: nothing more i think it's because i had child like this self.ref.child("categories").child(self.user.uid).childByAutoId().setValue(textField.text!) so it's not like setValue with a NSDictionnary String/String when i want to save the block

Comment: Check to make sure none of those variables are nil

Comment: it's like i want to do this : self.ref.child("categories").child(self.user.uid).setValue([Snap (-KTyha6hGYmx2x3yl6Za) BUSINESS, Snap (-KTyha6ilqqqsR0TQgbR) FAMILLE, Snap (-KTyha6ilqqqsR0TQgbS) AMIS, Snap (-KTyha6ilqqqsR0TQgbT) ECOLE, Snap (-KTyha6ilqqqsR0TQgbU) UNIVERSITÉ, Snap (-KTyha6ilqqqsR0TQgbV) SPORT, Snap (-KTyha6ilqqqsR0TQgbW) ACTIVITÉ, Snap (-KTyha6ilqqqsR0TQgbX) SOCIAL]
)  Maybe it's not possible

Comment: No I don't think you can set snapshots like that. Perhaps you mean to set it to an array of just the keys.

Comment: ok but if i did that when i will add a new key/value it will not a snapshot autoid... but a key like String (i don't know if i'm clear)... autoid begin by -...... other not